# How to replace string with asterisk(*) using strlen?

Tags: php, strlen

Hi please check my code:

```
<?php
$length='';
//$username="stackoverflow";
//$username="php";
$username=$_REQUEST['parameter'];
$len = strlen($username)-2;

for($i=1; $i<=$len; $i++){
    $length .= "*";
}

echo $username[0].$length.substr($username, -1);
?>
```

Above code i am using this code is working fine. But i need to customize code.

EX- if i use `stackoverflow` it should be `s***********w` and `php` should be `p*p`

My code is working but i need to any shortcut function to customize my php code. Share your knowledge

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/str_repeat) :)

Comment: @ljacqu `str_repeat()` working fine thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to combine `strlen()` with [`str_repeat()`](https://www.php.net/str_repeat) and [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/substr) for the beginning and ending character. Such a function could look like this:

```
function obfuscate_username($username) {
    if (strlen($username) < 3) {
        return $username;
    }
    else {
        return substr($username, 0, 1).str_repeat('*', strlen($username)-2).substr($username, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The PHP documentation for `str_repeat()` says an empty string will be returned if the second argument is negative, but it fails to mention that a warning will be output as well. So the check for length first helps avoid any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

```
$username=$_REQUEST['parameter'];
echo substr($username,0,1).str_repeat("*",strlen($username)-2).substr($username,-1);
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/cgRW8Flc)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = "stackoverflow";
echo substr_replace($a, str_repeat("*", strlen($a)-2), 1,strlen($a)-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
<?php
$str = "stackoverflow";
$len = strlen($str);

if($len>=3)
{
  $new_str = $str[0].str_repeat("*", $len-2).$str[$len-1];
}
else
{
  $new_str = $str;
}

echo $new_str;
?>
```

**[Example](https://eval.in/177330)**

Answer (score 0):

Get length of string:

```
$length = strlen($string);
```

Get first and last character:

```
$first = substr("abcdef", 0, 1);
$last = substr("abcdef", -1);
```

Create middle of the string:

```
$middle = str_repeat("*", $length-2);
```

Final get whole string:

```
return $first.$middle.$last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy: `$username[0]` adds the first character, `str_repeat` adds a character n times and `username[$len - 1]` adds the last character of your string.

```
$username = $_REQUEST["parameter"];
$len = strlen($username);
if ($len >= 2)
    return $username[0] . str_repeat("*", $len - 2) . $username[$len - 1];
else 
    return $username;
```